# Does shouldReloadTableForSearchString wait a while before executing?

Tags: objective-c

I am implementing search autocommplete. I am doing it without UISearchDisplayController/UISearchBar

A recurring problem is if I start doing something right after the guy press button then the program isn't "snappy".

A way around that is to use timer.

Then I've heard that UISearchController has a delegate to call.

Will that delegate solve my problem? What exactly does the delegate do? Wait a while after pressing button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that `searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString:` is called immediately when the text in the search field changes. So that would not help with your problem.